# Big Font Size, Thin Letters

Tags: css, fonts

Let's say I use `font-size:30px;` and `font-family:Verdana;`.

[image]

I need those letters to be big, but yet thin, so I tried `font-weight:lighter;`.

Yet nothing changes, some fonts will become smaller, some wont be affected.

How can I create big but thin letters? Is there a way in CSS, or these are specific fonts?

Comment: You'll have to use a different font. Try out numerical values as well: `font-weight: 100`, etc.

Comment: Not all fonts come in all weights. Try looking for a font on [Google webfonts](http://google.com/webfonts) that suits your needs.

Comment: Try with these values: 100, 200, 300. One of them should work. Also if you use Google web font's be sure that import this thin version of them.

Comment: Numerical Values didn't really work, after all, not all font weights work on all fonts, Google Webfonts has everything, yet I hate to use external stuff, but looks like I'm forced to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve a skinnier version of Verdana, due to the font not supporting certain weights, you will have to host your own version of the font, or use another font already hosted to achieve your look.

Some fonts do not support lighter/heavier versions of themselves - if they do, they may not align with the CSS numerical scale (as you pointed out).

From [here](http://elliotjaystocks.com/blog/font-weight-in-the-age-of-web-fonts/).

> Because so many professional quality web fonts come in a variety of
>   weights, it now makes much more sense to use the numerical scale than
>   it did when we only had to deal with ‘normal’ (400) and ‘bold’ (600).
>   Typically, a family’s weights can be mapped to these values:
>
> 100: Ultra Light
>
> 200: Thin
>
> 300: Light
>
> 400: Regular
>
> 500: Semi Bold
>
> 600: Bold
>
> 700: Extra Bold
>
> 800: Heavy
>
> 900: Ultra Heavy
>
> Note the keyword, there: typically. The reality, sadly, is that many
>   fonts just don’t conform to this pattern, like when a family has a
>   multitude of weights, or where their own definitions don’t necessarily
>   conform to the standard scale.

So, long story short, you will have to either host a "thinner" version of the font (one you either made/downloaded), or use a different font.

IMO Tahoma, Hedley or Geneva are similar-looking fonts, however these are not freely available - you can look on [Google fonts](http://google.com/fonts) for some, that both you and [@minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329352/big-font-size-thin-letters#comment21647087_15329352) pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

This is the closest thing I came up with.

```
div{
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:100;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Problems:
1. Only works with webkit browsers (Safari,Chrome)
2. If the background behind the text isn't a solid color then it will be visible that it is a text stroke.
http://jsfiddle.net/dru87/

Comment: Thanks for this; anti-aliasing in Webkit is very helpful in my situation!

Answer (score 1):

Choose a thin font  and apply [bigtext.js/fittext.js](http://www.zachleat.com/web/fittext-and-bigtext/) or [slabtext.js](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slabText/)

Answer (score 1):

Not all fonts supports all widths. If you are looking for some good thin fonts. You can take a look at these [thin google fonts](http://www.howtokickblogger.com/2013/04/thin-google-fonts-for-blog.html) list. They are free and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `font-weight` means asking for different-weight typefaces (specific fonts) from the font-family. The Verdana font family has no typeface lighter than normal, so you get just normal. This applies to most fonts that you can normally use on web pages.

In [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts), for example, you can find many font families with typefaces lighter than normal, e.g. Source Sans Pro has weights 200 and 300.

Note: The lightness of a typeface is relative to the font. What is light (200) in font family might correspond to what is normal (400) in another font family.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Include in  to load fonts from Google

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Step2: Add following css properties 
.text{
font-family: Lato, sans-serif;

font-weight: 100;

font-size: 7em;
}

Done!

will work definitely

For more info visit http://tobiasahlin.com/typesource/01-elements-of-html-and-css/